# How to enforce Azure Virtual Application base path?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, blazor

I have an Azure App Service which has two virtual applications (Asp.Net Core Blazor apps, if it's important) hosted within it. The virtual application URLS are something along the lines of

https://site.azurewebsites.net/site1

https://site.azurewebsites.net/site2

I have noticed that some of the internal routing seems to not be taking the virtual application path into account. For example, a link that takes the site to the "/" route navigates to https://site.azurewebsites.net instead of the appropriate "base" virtual application path. Is there some way of either handling this in my application or within the azure configuration?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Hassan's suggestions, on App Service, Each app has the default root path (/) mapped to D:\home\site\wwwroot, where your code is deployed by default. If your app root is in a different folder, or if your repository has more than one application ( as in your case), you can edit or add virtual applications and directories here.

To configure virtual applications and directories, specify each virtual directory and its corresponding physical path relative to the website root (D:\home). Optionally, you can select the Application checkbox to mark a virtual directory as an application.

From Azure Portal > Navigate to your  WebApp -> Settings (Configuration)-> Path Mapping> Virtual applications and directories.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ajay. This is already configured in my sites. Site 1 is site\wwwroot and Site2 is site\wwwroot2 and a separate virtual application. My issue is that the root path (/) on site 2 is taking me to the root path "/" instead of "/site2", despite them being separate virtual applications in a similar fashion to the one you describe. The only difference is that Site1 actually points to site\wwwroot.

Comment: After doing some additional troubleshooting, I noticed that, on Blazor pages, if I use href="" instead of href="/", the site will navigate to the expected page. Any routes that begin with "/" appear to go to the wwwroot site instead of the appropriate route within the virtual application. This discovery doesn't fully solve my issue unfortunately, as I also have Razor Pages for some Identity functionality that handle this routing differently that have shared components with the blazor side.

Comment: This is normal. "/" always goes to the root of the domain. You should always use "~/" server-side for URLs to take the application path into account.
"~/some-path" will become "/site1/some-path" or "/site2/some-path".

Answer (score 0):

if you browse via console Kudu console in your app service blade you will notice a directory, under wwwroot is the root directory which by default your application routes to. This you can change from App Settings blade option. Also in this directory you will find you can create other folders aka virtual applications which will work the way you want it to.